# I cannot figure out how I can fix this if statement

Tags: javascript

```
var count=1;
var temp="";
var end= window.prompt('enter the length');
var b = parseInt(end);

while(true){
  temp+="-";
  count++;
  if(count>b&&end!=null){
console.log("enter:" +end+ "= " + temp );
break;
 }
}
```

I have this code which is suppose to give me the output of "-" for each number the user enters so if i the user enters 2 the output should be "--". But when the user enters a string or number zero the output should be just "-".

Comment: Explain the problems you're having. If the user enters one million, is it suppose to output one million `-` or just seven ?

Comment: it's suppose to print one million of these -

Comment: Then I guess isNaN is the right answer, and there's an answer below that seems to be correct ?

Comment: it works for most the numbers even when put zero in there it works it just doesn't work when enter a string

Comment: Yes, and the answer is to check if the value is numeric, i.e. isNaN, and that's already been answered below.

Comment: Im getting a SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: I have tested the code on my answer with the following input: ('"'"''s;) and no syntax error was thrown. Check the jsfiddle link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @java - Did you just copy the code from jsFiddle? If so look out for "rogue" characters at the end there.

Comment: I don't know is just not working for me even on jsfiddle

Comment: Im supposed to test it for all these condition

Comment: the output should look like this-  enter: 4 = ----
enter: 1 = -
enter: 0 = -
enter: hello = -

Comment: @java This is exactly what happens with the code provided in my answer.

Comment: when using jsfiddle how come i don't see the results when i enter a number it does show me anything in the result

Comment: Open up the console in your browser (likely press F12), you will see the result.

Comment: Or use the 2nd fiddle provided in my answer. I changed the code to alert instead of console.log ..

Comment: is there anything else i can use besides isNaN or is there another way. just wondering

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a simpler way of doing what you want, as comments say, `isNaN` is what you need to verify you actually get a number.

```
var length = parseInt(window.prompt('enter the length'), 10);
alert(new Array(isNaN(length) ? 2 : length  + 1).join('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 1;
var temp = "";
var end = window.prompt('enter the length');
var b = parseInt(end);

while (true) {
    temp += "-";
    count++;

    // if the user entered a valid integer that is not 0
    if (!isNaN(b) && b !== 0) {
        if (count > b && end != null) {
            console.log("enter:" + end + "= " + temp);
            break;
        }

    // else the user entered 0 or some other input that isn't an integer
    } else {
        console.log("enter:" + end + "= -");
        break;
    }
}​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxLw2/10/)

[**FIDDLE WITH ALERTS**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxLw2/12/)